# Getting token metadata by name/symbol?

Tags: metaplex-js, metadata, javascript

Given a token symbol (let's say `$RAY`), how can I programatically get all token addresses with that symbol?

I know I can pull metadata by contract using:

```
import { Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';

const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection);
const metadataPda = metaplex.nfts().pdas().metadata({ mint: mintAddress });
```

But how do I do this starting with the symbol?

Answer (score 1):

May be try to use getParsedProgramAccounts (https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedProgramAccounts)

The program should be mpl token metadata, but it implies that you know the structure of the data in order to filter by token name, which i don't, but i guess you can find it on their github